# Creating java date object from year,month,day

Tags: java, date, time, calendar

```
int day = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("day"));  // 25
int month = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("month")); // 12
int year = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("year")); // 1988

System.out.println(year);

Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.set(year, month, day, 0, 0);  

b.setDob(c.getTime());

System.out.println(b.getDob());
```

Output is:

> 1988
>   Wed Jan 25 00:00:08 IST 1989

I am passing `25 12 1988` but I get `25 Jan 1989`. Why?

Comment: What is b in the code?

Comment: For new readers to the question I recommend you don’t use `Calendar`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `LocalDate` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). See [the answer by Przemek](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33892250/5772882).

Answer (score 140, accepted):

Months are zero-based in Calendar. So 12 is interpreted as december + 1 month. Use

```
c.set(year, month - 1, day, 0, 0);
```

Comment: IBM API designers, JavaScript API designers. Other than that, probably nobody. Note that Calendar is now obsoleted by th the Java 8 java.time API, which does the right thing.

Answer (score 91):

That's my favorite way prior to Java 8:

```
Date date = new GregorianCalendar(year, month - 1, day).getTime();
```

I'd say this is a bit cleaner than:

```
calendar.set(year, month - 1, day, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Month could be specified using `Calendar` constants eg. `Calendar.FEBRUARY`.

Comment: Beware, the months used to be numbered from zero in Java 7. Use constants to avoid trouble.

Comment: A point to make - the two render different results when calling `getTime()`. Setting info in the constructor gives time at the start of day where as the latter approach uses the current time. See the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html#GregorianCalendar()). So the first is probably a better approach, assuming what people are actually trying to do.

Comment: This is returning a Date, which by definition is in UTC. But with your JVM *not* also set to UTC you won't be getting what you expect. The returned Date will have what the UTC time was at the beginning of the day of the date you entered (assuming constructor form). I entered my birthday and got the date before, b/c the TZ of my computer is + hours from UTC.

Answer (score 44):

## java.time

Using `java.time` framework built into Java 8

```
int year = 2015;
int month = 12;
int day = 22;
LocalDate.of(year, month, day); //2015-12-22
LocalDate.parse("2015-12-22"); //2015-12-22
//with custom formatter 
DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy");
LocalDate.parse("22-12-2015", formatter); //2015-12-22
```

If you need also information about time(hour,minute,second) use some conversion from `LocalDate` to `LocalDateTime`

```
LocalDate.parse("2015-12-22").atStartOfDay() //2015-12-22T00:00
```

Comment: Good Answer, but specify a time zone if known. A `LocalDate` has no time zone and so does not represent an exact moment on the timeline. If your context indicates a time zone, apply it to get a `ZonedDateTime` object:  `LocalDate.parse("2015-12-22").atStartOfDay( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) )`

Answer (score 11):

Java's Calendar representation is not the best, they are working on it for Java 8. I would advise you to use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) or another similar library.

Here is a quick example using LocalDate from the Joda Time library:

```
LocalDate localDate = new LocalDate(year, month, day);
Date date = localDate.toDate();
```

[Here](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/quickstart.html) you can follow a quick start tutorial.

Answer (score 6):

See [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#set%28int,%20int,%20int%29):

> month - the value used to set the MONTH calendar field. Month value is
>   0-based. e.g., 0 for January.

So, the month you set is the first month of next year.

Answer (score 0):

Make your life easy when working with dates, timestamps and durations. Use HalDateTime from

http://sourceforge.net/projects/haldatetime/?source=directory

For example you can just use it to parse your input like this:

```
HalDateTime mydate = HalDateTime.valueOf( "25.12.1988" );
System.out.println( mydate );   // will print in ISO format: 1988-12-25
```

You can also specify patterns for parsing and printing.

Comment: It looks like you’re promoting your own library class? That’s probably permitted, but it would look nicer if you mention if you’re a main developer of `HalDateTime`.

Comment: I did not downvote. However life never is easy with dates. Your library wont change that fact.

Comment: Why downvote? My library dates from 2013. All functionality is available in java.time as specified in JSR 310 which I personally find is one of the best designed APIs. I fully recommend using that one.