# How to get a Date object from year,month and day?

Tags: java, date

When I used the following code, the `Date` Object was wrong.

```
Date date = new Date(day.getYear(), day.getMonth(), day.getDay());
```

Can anyone tell me how to get the Date Object From the value of year, month and day?

Comment: What was wrong in your method? What was the `day` object originally and what `date` object did you get?

Comment: See this near duplicate: [Creating java date object from year,month,day](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16499228/642706)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without knowing more I'd have to guess but probably you didn't read the JavaDoc on that *deprecated* constructor:

> **year** the year minus 1900.
>   **month** the month between 0-11.
>   **date** the day of the month between 1-31.

As you can see, if you want to create a date for today (Aug 5th 2015) you'd need to use `new Date (115, 7, 5);`

If you see that documentation you are free to guess why this is deprecated and should not be used in any new code. :)

Comment: when I used new Date(115,7,5) get the year is 115 not 2015

Comment: @JohnnyTsai in that case please add more info, e.g. the exact class name (including package), Java version used, how you check the year etc. Also note the JavaDoc on `getYear()`: `the year represented by this date, minus 1900.`, i.e. you'd get 115 back.

Comment: @JohnnyTsai Because `Date.getYear()` returns the passed year (*115*) and not the correctly adjusted year. For example try `new Date(115,7,5).toString()` and then stop using deprecated methods. Btw some more research would be great.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `Calendar` class to achieve this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Date date = new Date (115, 7, 5);
    System.out.println("date     = " + date);

    Calendar calendar = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 5);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, 7);
    calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2015);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    date = calendar.getTime();
    System.out.println("calendar = " + date);

    // or create directly a new clanedar instance
    // thanks Tom to mention this
    calendar = new GregorianCalendar(2015, 7, 5);
    date = calendar.getTime();
    System.out.println("calendar = " + date);
}
```

**output**

```
date     = Wed Aug 05 00:00:00 CEST 2015
calendar = Wed Aug 05 00:00:00 CEST 2015
calendar = Wed Aug 05 00:00:00 CEST 2015
```

Comment: If you're using a `GregorianCalendar`, then why you're not using `new GregorianCalendar(2015, 7, 5)` instead of setting each field manually?

Comment: @Tom Good question. Maybe I had something else in mind. (it's early in the morning ;-) )

Comment: Btw, `date = new Date(calendar.getTimeInMillis());` can be shortened to `date = calendar.getTime();` :)

Comment: @Thomas It's not my day today... `inject coffee - brain 1.0 needs a reboot` ;-)

Comment: `Your caffeine levels are critically low, please find a coffee maker immediately to prevent brain shutdown.` - I feel the same ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a workaround if you're stuck to Java < 8, but it's very ugly:

```
java.util.Date date = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy").parse("05.08.2015");
```

as @Thomas already stated, the default Constructor for date/month/year is deprecated. Probably take a look at [this link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-date-time-2125367.html) if you have access to Java8.

Answer (score 0):

you should use getDate() instead of getDay() method to get the day because getDay() return the day of week not the day of month

Comment: Day Class is defied by myself.

Answer (score 0):

- **`int   getYear()`**
        Deprecated. As of JDK version 1.1, replaced by **`Calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR) - 1900.`**
- **`int    getMonth()`**
        Deprecated. As of JDK version 1.1, replaced by **`Calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH).`**
- **`int     getDay()`**
        Deprecated. As of JDK version 1.1, replaced by **`Calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK).`**

Hence use :

**`Date date = new Date(Calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR) - 1900, Calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), Calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK));`**

**Recomendation** : Use [**Joda-Time**](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/)

Comment: If you're setting up a `Calendar` anyways, you'd not need to use that constructor at all. Just make sure to set the time part to 0 (hour, minutes, seconds, millis) and call `getTime()` on the calendar.

Comment: As for the recommendation: I agree with you for Java 7 and prior. Java 8 has a new date api which is similar to Joda Time.

Comment: @Thomas , you are absolutely correct, but as the OP requirement is `Date` object, this is a solution.