# Getting range of dates from two different dates

Tags: java, android, calendar, kotlin, daterangepicker

I have two dates: initial and final. I need to be able to quickly get all the interim days, given the month. The problem is that every digit in the date is due to a variable. The reason of it is that I use Date Picker with range, but all values are given separately (like startDay, startMonth, startYear and endDay, endMonth, endYear). So, I need to get all dates between those dates. It must look like this:

```
"24/02/2018|25/02/2018|26/02/2018|27/02/2018|28/02/2018|01/03/2018"
```

Look at this: 01/**03**/2018.

**SOLUTION:**

```
fun getDaysBetweenDates(startdate: Date, enddate: Date): List<String> {
    val dates = ArrayList<String>()
    val calendar = GregorianCalendar()
    calendar.time = startdate

    while (calendar.time.before(enddate)) {
        val result = calendar.time
        val formatter = SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy")
        val today = formatter.format(result)
        today.split("|")
        dates.add(today)
        calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1)
    }
    return dates
}
```

Well, thanks for helping to OleV.V. and asm0dey.

Comment: Please search. This has been asked and answered before.

Comment: It’s also been asked and answered more than once. [Here, for example: how to get a list of dates between two dates in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2689379/how-to-get-a-list-of-dates-between-two-dates-in-java). By all means go search for more, it’s unlikely I’ve found the very best answers yet.

Comment: @OleV.V. ouch. Sorry, I was not online. So, I searched, but for some reason I did not find it. (Apparently Google did not produce normal results, but here I always forget that I can search directly). Well, now I'll look at what you offer.

Comment: @OleV.V. well, if it's gonna be helpful, check out my edit. Again, if it's gonna be helpful....

Comment: Thx for the edit. “…ThreeTenABP, but, how I understood, it's very inefficient to use.” Beg to differ. `LocalDate` from ThreeTenABP, I expect it to be efficient both in terms of efficient code writing, efficient maintenance and efficient runtime performance. I got no idea from where you got that other statement.

Comment: To create a date object from three integers: [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33892250/5772882). Then use the other answers. To format the dates into the format you want in your output string: [How to format LocalDate to string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28177370/how-to-format-localdate-to-string) If it’s hard to find, it may be because you are asking too many questions in one. For best results try to separate into single tasks, both when you search and when you post a question.

Comment: @OleV.V. Well, it's written in the official github repository. Anyway, I'll try it. I'm just a little bit tired and want to get answer to all my questions, oh well.

Comment: Do you mean this sentence? “the threetenbp uses a JAR resource for loading timezone information. This is an extremely inefficient mechanism on Android.” It’s talking exactly about the inecciciency that ThreeTenABP *overcomes* (compared to pure ThreeTen Backport).

Comment: And, then it is understandable. Anyway, in one of the links, what you threw off (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2689379/how-to-get-a-list-of-dates-between-two-dates-in-java) was a pretty good answer, which almost completely came up to me. The fact is that I need a short date, that is, without explaining the day, month and time. So, maybe you know how to do this? Anyway, thank you very much for helping to find the answer that is completely appropriate.

Comment: What do you mean by “without explaining the day, month and time”?

Comment: Another tip, depending on the comparison you’re to do, it may be easier to process a list of dates than a long string. So you may split the string from JSON at the pipe or vertical bar symbol `|` and parse each element into a `LocalDate` to obtain such a list.

Comment: 1. Why do you think `Date` class is deprecated? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html it's not deprecated at least in Java 8. 2. In my example you can use any dates in any months. 3. Please, expose your exact problem — parse dates? find interim dates? You can build date string from digits and parse it if you need. You can construct Calendar from digits — it's perfectly affordable too…

Comment: I think the OP meant that the `Date` constructor taking three `int` arguments is deprecated, @asm0dey. I believe it has been deprecated since Java 1.1, that is, for more than 20 years.

Comment: @OleV.V. well... It's deprecated in favour of calendar API, so that's easy to create calendar and get date from it

Comment: Ok. I've fixed all I need. See my new edit. There'll be solution for my problem.

Comment: @ArsenSaruhanyan you can mark answer as correct — your solution is pretty close my :)

Comment: @asm0dey done :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you can achieve what you want with simple while loop — just add days one by one to initial date intil you'll reach end of the date range.

So it'll look like

```
val interimDates = arrayListOf<Date>()
var initial: Date = Date()// obtained earlier
val c = Calendar.getInstance()
c.time = initial
while (initial < finalDate /*also obtained earlier*/) {
    c.add(Calendar.DATE, 1)
    interimDates.add(c.time)
    initial = c.time
}
```

At the end `interimDates` will contain all interim dates

Comment: It should work. But the `Date` and `Calendar` classes are long outdated, and despite their names they only inaccurately match the requirements since they entail more than a date in the calendar. Better to add [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project and use `org.threeten.bp.LocalDate`.

Comment: @OleV.V. if it would be Java - I would propose to use LocalDate, but task is that simple that you just don't need one more library in your project