# Problems while calculating the difference between days

Tags: java, date, gregorian-calendar

i am pretty new to coding, so this might be a stupid question, but I can't find any solution. I want to calculate the difference (in days) between to dates. It works most of the time, but when the month changes, I get weird solutions. 

**First example:** 
today - 30 September 2018 = 78 Days,
today - 31 September 2018 = 79 Days (??), 
today - 1 October 2018 = 80 Days

**Second example:** 
today - 31 August 2018 = 49 Days, 
today - 1 September 2018 = 49 Days

The code

```
private static int[] abstandTage(GregorianCalendar date1, ArrayList<GregorianCalendar> csvDate)
{
    int[] abstand = new int[csvDate.size()];
    int i = 0;
    while ( i < csvDate.size() )
    {
        long diffInMillis = csvDate.get(i).getTimeInMillis() - date1.getTimeInMillis();
        long tage = diffInMillis / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24;
        abstand[i] = (int) tage;
        i++ ;
    }

    return abstand;
}
```

date1 is a predefined Date, csvDate is a list with dates. Can anybody help me?

Thanks in advance
Alex

Comment: Better not to use the long outdated and poorly designed `GregorianCalendar` class and better to let a library method do the calculation for you. For example `ChronoUnit.DAYS.between()`, passing two `LocalDate` instances. Those classes are in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: I would recommend to program against an interface by changing the signature to `int[] abstandTage(GregorianCalendar date1, List<GregorianCalendar> csvDate)`, more information about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface).

Comment: You results are unexpected, I agree. From today (13 July) to 30 September should be 79 days. To 1 September should be 50 days. Sounds like the days in September are wrong? How are you creating the `GregorianCalendar` objects? Could you [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference in days between two dates in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3299972/difference-in-days-between-two-dates-in-java)

Comment: Possible near-duplicate of [Creating java date object from year,month,day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16499228/creating-java-date-object-from-year-month-day)

Answer (score 1):

The array of differences can be calculated using `ChronoUnit`. You can also use a stream to further simplify your implementation:

```
private static int[] abstandTage(GregorianCalendar date1,
          ArrayList<GregorianCalendar> csvDate) {

    return csvDate.stream()
            .mapToInt(csvdate -> (int) 
               ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(date1.toZonedDateTime(), csvdate.toZonedDateTime()))
            .toArray();
}
```

Comment: If we cannot avoid the `GregorianCalendar` class, this is the way to go. Still better if the caller would pass `LocalDate` or another modern date and time class in.

Answer (score 1):

This happens if you create your `GregorianCalendar` objects as for example `new GregorianCalendar(2018, 7, 13)` for July 13. `GregorianCalendar` uses a weird month numbering, so you are not getting July 13.

The solution is to throw that long outdated and poorly designed class away and create your dates using for example `LocalDate.of(2018, 7, 13)` or even better, `LocalDate.of(2018, Month.JULY, 13)`. Then use `ChronoUnit.DAYS.between`  for finding the number of days between the dates.

**Link:** [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API.

Comment: Thanks to your comment (weird numbering), I found a solution. Nevertheless, I am going to try the way you suggested here with Chronounit. Thanks for your efforts! Really appreciated.

Comment: @dribble290 The old legacy date-time classes really are a bloody awful mess. Sun, Oracle, and the JCP all agreed to replace them with *java.time* for a reason. Actually, for *many* reasons. You won't regret adopting *java.time*.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, you will have to use **LocalDate** here :

```
SimpleDateformat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
Date date1 = sdf.parse("20180713);
Date date2 = sdf.parse("20180930");
LocalDate startDate = 
date1.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
LocalDate endDate = 
date2.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
long days = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(startDate, endDate);
return days;
```

Conversion from Gregorian to Date is done via :

```
Date newDate = new Date(date1.getTime());
```

Comment: Thanks for wanting to contribute. Yes to `LocalDate´, but when you can use `LocalDate` from `java.time`, is see no reason whatsoever to use the old-fashioned `Date` nor the notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat`. Use `java.time` exclusively. It’s also simpler.

Comment: As Ole V.V. commented, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). Do not mix the legacy classes were entirely supplanted by *java.time*, so no need to ever mix.