# Converting date to timestamp returns the wrong date

Tags: java, android, date

I have the following function that should return a timestamp. This code works when the date is entered in a string format using slashes like the following: "2019/3/4" but does not work right when using `new Date(year, month, day).`

```
import java.util.Date;

public static Long dateToTimestamp(Date date) {
        return date == null ? null : date.getTime();
}
```

```
dateToTimestamp(new Date(2019, 3, 4) ---> 61512498000000 or, when converted, Friday, April 4, 3919 5:00:00 AM
```

What is going on?

Comment: ```@Deprecated
    public Date(int year, int month, int date) {
        this(year, month, date, 0, 0, 0);
    }```
It's a deprecated method. Also add the error you're getting.

Comment: try `2019-1990` instead of `2019`

Comment: @Shahal I am not getting an error logged anywhere as the value is just wrong after converted.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating java date object from year,month,day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16499228/creating-java-date-object-from-year-month-day) I recommend [the answer by przemek](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33892250/5772882).

Comment: I recommend you consider throwing away the long outmoded and poorly designed `Date` class and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with. And I certainly even more strongly recommend you under all circumstances stay far away from the deprecated constructors and method of that outdated `Date` class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `Date(int year, int month, int date)`, The parameter should be like this:

> ```
> @param   year    the year minus 1900.
> @param   month   the month between 0-11.
> @param   date    the day of the month between 1-31.
> ```

Since `Date(int year, int month, int date)` is deprecated, You can use `Calendar` and `set` like below to get desired `date`

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
calendar.set(2019, Calendar.MARCH, 4)
Long timeInMillis = calendar.timeInMillis

// timeInMillis should be 1551718624170 equivalent to Mon Mar 04 2019
```

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

If you want to get the first moment of the day on that date as seen in UTC, transformed into a count of milliseconds since 1970-01-01T00:00Z :

```
LocalDate             // Represent a date, without time-of-day and without time zone.  
.of( 2019 , 3 , 4 )   // Determine a date. Uses sane numbering, 1-12 for January-December.
.atStartOfDay(        // Determine first moment of the day.
    ZoneOffset.UTC    // Get the first moment as seen at UTC (an offset of zero hours-minutes-days.
)                     // Returns a `ZonedDateTime` object.
.toInstant()          // Convert from a `ZonedDateTime` to a simple `Instant` object, which is always in UTC, and has methods to get count-from-epoch.
.toEpochMilli()       // Get a count of milliseconds since the epoch reference of first moment of 1970 to UTC.
```

## *java.time*

You are using terrible date-time classes that were supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

To get a count of milliseconds or whole seconds since the epoch reference of first moment of 1970 in UTC, 1970-01-01T00:00Z, use [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html).

```
long millis = Instant.now().toEpochMilli() ;
```

Or:

```
long seconds = Instant.now().getEpochSecond() ;
```

For a date, you must determine the first moment of the day on that date. This not always the time 00:00, so let *java.time* determine that moment. Doing so requires a time zone. The day starts earlier in the East than in the west, varying around the globe by time zone.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2019 , 3 , 4 ) ;
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ld.atStartOfDay( z ) ;
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant() ;
long millis = Instant.now().toEpochMilli() ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

[image: Table of which java.time library to use with which version of Java or Android]

Comment: @OleV.V. I altered your edit at top, changing your time zone to `ZoneOffset.UTC` as I was trying to show UTC up top and zoned down below. Thanks for that edit and the others.

Comment: Sorry, I had paid too little attention there. Thanks for reporting back.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the JavaDoc of the Date method. It states that the value of the first argument year should be

> `the year minus 1900.`

So the correct version of calling **dateToTimestamp** method would be

`dateToTimestamp(new Date(119, 3, 4)` .

This would give you `1554316200000`. When Converted it would be 4th April 2019.

**Note** that the value of the month starts from 0 for January, 1 for February and so on.